# Macbook retina picking up iPad retina media query

Tags: css, ipad, media-queries, retina-display

I have the following media query, to select iPad retina and smaller displays.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape), 
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) and (orientation : landscape),
only screen and (max-width : 1080px){

}
```

The problem I have is, on Macbook Pro retina's the styles are also picked up.

I don't have a retina to test on, so I'm having trouble debugging.

Can anyone see the conflicting rule?

Answer (score 1):

You should use simplest media query. Here the link i use for apple's device : http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/

Comment: As I said in the question, I need to to work with smaller displays as well.

Comment: You can use only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 768px) for exemple for smaller device. Plus only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) and (orientation : landscape) selects Macbook Pro retina's for me.